# How to use rails bundler behind a authenticated proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy

I am new to ruby and getting started to learn ruby on rails.
I am behind authenticated proxy network.

I researched on the internet, however the answers didn't work for me.

Password has special characters

I have exported http_proxy in ruby shell

```
export http_proxy=ht tp://foo:b\@r\@192.168.1.1:8080
```

When  issued `bundle update` I get below error

```
:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:213:in `initialize': the scheme http does not accept registry part: foo:b@r@192.168.1.1:8080 (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb:84:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:214:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:214:in `parse'
```

I tried remove \ before 2 in both places, but didn't work.

I have put this content in .gemrc file in the folder where I create first_app
Yet didn't work.

Anyone who has used Rails behind authenticated proxy, please help me?

Comment: When i change gem file from https://rubygems.org to http://rubygems.org (removing https)
I get below Error
[code]
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from http://rubygems.org/[/code]

Comment: Finally i switched to cntlm to fix it.